# ruby try_convert class method not converting

Tags: ruby

In the ruby doc of the String class (version 2.2.0) I've found the class method 'try_convert' that, qouting the doc itself should do:

```
Try to convert obj into a String, using #to_str method. Returns converted string or nil if obj cannot be converted for any reason.
```

So i've decided to test it, and i've done it with the following code and results.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

z=BigDecimal.new "12.4"
puts z
zc=String.try_convert(z)

i=365
ic=String.try_convert(i)

puts "Test of try_convert on a bigdecimal. The result is: #{zc.nil? ? 'nil' : zc }"
puts "While, the #to_s method on z returns: #{z.to_s}"

puts "The integer i, converted with try_convert is: #{ic.nil? ? 'nil' : ic}"
puts "While, the #to_s method on i returns: #{i.to_s}"

class MyClass 
end

c=MyClass.new
cc=String.try_convert(c)
puts "Test of try_convert on a custom class. The result is: \"#{cc.nil? ? 'nil' : cc}\""
puts "While, the #to_s method on c returns \"#{c.to_s}\""
```

Results:

Test of try_convert on a bigdecimal. The result is: **nil**
While, the #to_s method on z returns: 0.124E2

The integer i, converted with try_convert is: **nil**
While, the #to_s method on i returns: 365

Test of try_convert on a custom class. The result is: "**nil**"
While, the #to_s method on c returns #<MyClass:0x98d12d4>

So i'm quite perplexed: in the beginning, it seemed to me quite clear that try_convert would have tried to call the to_s method on the argument, but this examples seems to show that this isn't true. What am I missing? And what is this method meant for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_convert` actually attempts to call `to_str` on the argument, not `to_s`:

```
class Foo
  def to_str
    "hello!"
  end
end

String.try_convert(Foo.new) # => "hello!"
```

`to_str` is usually used to indicate that your object can be used in place of a String (not the same as just having a String representation).

Answer (score 1):

I'll just quote two lines from your own question, with emphasis added:

> it seemed to me quite clear that `try_convert` would have tried to call the **`to_s`** method on the argument
>
> Try to convert `obj` into a `String`, using **`#to_str`** method.

Spot the difference?

Comment: of course i did. i hope that my mistake may be useful for some other people. I usually don't pay much attention to each single name, be it a method name or whatever, but on the overall 'naming convention'. For example singular and plural names in rails are now quite clear to me, and I don't confuse them because I expected them to exist with a different, clear meaning. Here i didn't even know about the existence of a second, slightly different way of getting a string from an object so wen i saw it i didn't notice that it actually was a completely distinct name.